# ASP.NET - Global location to execute some code?

Tags: asp.net, global

I have a newbie .net question.

Where would be a good place to write some code that executes globally before each page load?  Some operations that I would be doing are:

a) open a database connection
b) check the session to see if user is logged in
c) maybe initialize a few objects

I was thinking of doing this in a master file, but wasn't sure if that's a good idea.  And maybe for each of the operations listed, maybe there's a feature in .Net that does it already, so that I don't have to "re-invent" the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a base page that all pages inheriet from (except master pages as these have a different base class)

You could then override PreLoad on the base page and do your checks in there.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a base class that derives from `Page`, and has an implementation of `Page_Load` that performs the operations you want.  Then you have to change all of your pages to inherit from this new base class.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [Global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx) file.

Comment: Perhaps, but which event in particular has access to session state etc? http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net_globalasax.asp

Comment: Im interested which event gets fired for all page loads also :)

Comment: Not working, none of the events of global.asax have access to the User object (all nullreferenceexception). Can't use it to authenticate users.